# Migration issue svn to git using subgit

Tags: subgit

I am trying to migrate svn to git using subgit.

```
I followed the steps from https://subgit.com/howto.html

I could successfully configure. I am getting following on exception on Installation phase.

subgit install banking.git

exception is as follows,

[2016-10-10 09:54:21.802][subgit-install][1] Closed random access file 'C:\Dev\subgit-3.2.2\bin\banking.git\subgit\daemon.lock'
[2016-10-10 09:54:21.808][subgit-install][1] Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
org.tmatesoft.translator.util.e: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
    at org.tmatesoft.translator.process.t.<clinit>(SourceFile:16)
    at org.tmatesoft.translator.process.win32.a.b(SourceFile:120)
```

I tried to fix by adding jna-3.2.5.jar in classpath and C:\Dev\subgit-3.2.2\bin\banking.git\subgit\lib folders as well. but couldnt fix it.

```
Could you please advise on it. 

Thanks
```

Comment: This particular case is being discussed through SubGit support channels at the moment. We'll publish any resolution on that as soon as it's available.

Comment: According to our information, the problem was temporary IO error which Rajkumar managed to fix.

Comment: yeah it is been fixed. There is a restriction in our organization to run any code other than Dev folder. Subgit install explore dll files in tmp folder and process. Since i dont have access to execute from tmp it failed initially. Now i have created tmp folder under Dev folder then set into environment variable. Now it got fixed. Thanks to subgit team.